# Using children selector in jQ

Tags: jquery, css

To override this type of CSS via jQ

```
#parentEle > div {
    display:none;
}
```

what is it in jQ speak

```
var $foo = $('#parentEle');
$($foo > 'div').css({display: 'inline'});
```

?

Comment: Here is the [Selectors category](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). This should give you a good enough grasp on what you have to do. Happy reading :)

Comment: It would be the same as in CSS. `$('#parentEle > div').css({display: 'inline'});`

Comment: `$('> div', $foo).css({display: 'inline'});`

Comment: @adeneo, nah, the "relative child selector" (`"> something"`) [has been deprecated for a while](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/child-selector-elem-context-deprecated).

Comment: I meant specifically the `$($foo > 'div')` part... is that correct? @FrédéricHamidi, what's your suggestion as an up-to-date method?

Comment: @user, if you really want to cache `$foo`, then I would suggest `$foo.children("div")`, but you should clarify this in your question. Otherwise, j08691's comment is most probably your answer. *Remember to read the docs* :)

Comment: j's example uses actual object name, I'm trying to find out if using the jQ var name as I have done it is correct. Your way is probably what I was looking for. Thanks all.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - didn't know that, it's probably because it's a strange syntax that doesn't work with any native methods, such as `querySelector()`, and as such requires internal iteration an is slower than just using `children()` or `$('#parent > child')`, which would be just as easy in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var $foo = $('#parentEle');
$foo.children('div').css({display: 'inline'});
```